# Extracting data from pdf using AWS textract

Tags: amazon-web-services, nlp, text-extraction, amazon-rekognition, amazon-textract

I have a pdf, i can extract text and other data from AWS textract but there are bar charts, graphs etc, i need way to extract data from those as well, not just labels but what those graphs represent.

i tried using aws rekognition but, it also provides labels.

Answer (score 1):

That is not something that is currently offered by AWS managed AI services such as Textract or Rekognition.

To achieve this you would need to train your own model on SageMaker to do such a task.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/how-it-works-training.html